# Цикл в C# не проходит последнюю итерацию

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь написать скрипт для Unity для игры наподобие пятнашек но с препятствиями. Ниже метод который отрисовывает доску при запуске приложения

```
public void CreateBoard()
{
    Tile[,] tileArray = new Tile[xSize, ySize];
    float xPos = transform.position.x;
    float yPos = transform.position.y;
    Vector2 tileSize = tileGO.spriteRenderer.bounds.size;
    for (int x=0; x< xSize; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y< ySize; y++)
        {
            if ((_wallCoordinates[wallIndex].X == x) && (_wallCoordinates[wallIndex].Y == y))
            {
                Wall wall = Instantiate(wallGO, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                wall.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
                wall.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos + (tileSize.x * x), yPos + (tileSize.y * y), 0f);
                wallIndex++;
            }
            else if (x % 2 == 0)
            {
                Tile tile = Instantiate(tileGO, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                tile.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
                tile.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos + (tileSize.x * x), yPos + (tileSize.y * y), 0f);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

По итогу, если оставлять только один if(при чем любой из 2х) в данном коде то всё работает корректно, но если пытаться оставить оба то возникает ошибка в unity IndexOutOfRangeException и последний столбец игровой доски не отрисовывается.

Пытался и код переписать и интернет весь облазил и отладчиком всё прошел. На отладчике заметил что при x=4 код просто выходит из цикла и идёт делать свои дальнейшие дела. Абсолютно не понимаю в чем проблема, может было у кого такое?

добавил ассеты сюда github.com/ElessaR-coder/55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращение `_wallCoordinates[wallIndex]` возвращает исключение, так как `wallIndex` больше либо равен `_wallCoordinates.Length`.

Решить можно как-то так

```
if (wallIndex < _wallCoordinates.Length && _wallCoordinates[wallIndex].X == x && _wallCoordinates[wallIndex].Y == y)
{
    // ...
}
```

Ну и внесите `wallIndex` из поля в сам метод, а то при повторном вызове `CreateBoard()` стены не отрисуются.

Comment: большое спасибо!!!